# Is Microsoft Workflow Foundation really used?

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation

Today, I had a training on "Microsoft Workflow Foundation".

While I think the idea is neat, I still see it as a *Proof Of Concept* and not as a real-life solution. Building an entire application without having to type a single line of code (or only a few of them) seems just wrong.

Have you ever used this technology and if so, can it *really* fit to big company projects ? What drawbacks/advantages have you got using it ?

Comment: This should be community wiki. It is rather subjective.

Comment: it is used in dynamics crm, sharepoint etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see it replacing an entire application, but more likely used in the architecture of an application to make it easier to maintain and build, since business logic is separated out.

In previous application I've built, we used our own workflow solution to make our site easier to maintain and also to add new content and controls quickly without recompiling & redeploying.

MWF can definitely have a place in even small applications, depending on it's needs.

Answer (score 1):

Workflow is just a part of a larger application, just like your entire app isn't WPF or ADO. And it is certainly used in real applications and very useful. Things to look for where it is a good fit are items that behave as small projects in an applications like a sales orders, hiring a new person or building a house. All thee have a start, go through multiple steps, have an ending and you are likely to manage multiple in your application. Describe the "project" steps in one or more workflows and start one for each occurrence.

As this is a very common occurrence I believe far more developers could benefit from using workflow in their applications.

Answer (score 0):

Lately I've been using it to replace those parts of the codebase that are really messy as far as the branching and looping logic is concerned.  When you can visualize that stuff in a picture, and just create some custom activities to perform your logic, it makes knowing exactly what is going on much easier.

The entire application wasn't rewritten, for example there's really no reason to do any CRUD type operations with workflow, but its been very helpful for some of the "heavy lifting" operations.